How to verify the signature in anchor that i created using nacl in js
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use ed25519_dalek::{ Signature, PublicKey, Verifier };

declare_id!("bHPU6ehyAy6ywvVkmVwV1XUx4DQzymwL4DoqYcgYnuK");

#[program]
pub mod demo {
    use super::*;



    pub fn verify_signature_instruction(
        ctx: Context<VerifySignature>,
        signature_bytes: [u8; 64],
        message: Vec<u8>
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let signature = Signature::from_bytes(&signature_bytes).map_err(
            |_| MyError::InvalidSignature
        )?;
        let public_key = PublicKey::from_bytes(&ctx.accounts.public_key.key.to_bytes()).map_err(
            |_| MyError::InvalidSignature
        )?;

        if public_key.verify(&message, &signature).is_ok() {
            msg!("Signature is valid");
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(MyError::InvalidSignature.into())
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct VerifySignature<'info> {
    /// CHECK: The account that holds the public key to verify the signature.
    pub public_key: AccountInfo<'info>,
}

#[error_code]
pub enum MyError {
    #[msg("Invalid signature")]
    InvalidSignature,
    #[msg("Unauthorized access")]
    Unauthorized,
    #[msg("Insufficient funds")]
    InsufficientFunds,
    // Add more error variants as needed
}

and my Cargo.toml looks like:
   [package]
name = "demo"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "demo"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []
[workspace]
resolver = "2"
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = { version = "0.29.0", features = ["init-if-needed"] }
ed25519-dalek = "1.0.1"

sha2 = "0.9"

and my testcase looks like
    it("should verify signature", async () => {
    const message = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    const messageBytes = decodeUTF8(message);
    console.log(" ~ it ~ messageBytes:", messageBytes)

    const signature = nacl.sign.detached(messageBytes, secretKey4);
    console.log(" ~ describe ~ signature:", signature);
    const verifySignature = await program.methods
      .verifySignatureInstruction(Array.from(signature), Buffer.from(messageBytes))
      .accounts({publicKey:acc4.publicKey})
      .rpc().then().catch((err) => {console.log(err)});
  });
});

but when I run my test case I am getting following error
    SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/yudizsolutionsltd/Documents/signature solana/demo/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5923:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/yudizsolutionsltd/Documents/signature solana/demo/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5880:20)
    at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (/Users/yudizsolutionsltd/Documents/signature solana/demo/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:370:21)
    at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (/Users/yudizsolutionsltd/Documents/signature solana/demo/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:160:14)
    at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (/Users/yudizsolutionsltd/Documents/signature solana/demo/node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16) {
  logs: [
    'Program EFghe4J4DhzdhBk9M8tS2efo8GXTfgJddhf5g5cQ9Q32 invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: VerifySignatureInstruction',
    'Program EFghe4J4DhzdhBk9M8tS2efo8GXTfgJddhf5g5cQ9Q32 consumed 200000 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program EFghe4J4DhzdhBk9M8tS2efo8GXTfgJddhf5g5cQ9Q32 failed: exceeded CUs meter at BPF instruction'
  ],
  programErrorStack: ProgramErrorStack {
    stack: [
      [PublicKey [PublicKey(EFghe4J4DhzdhBk9M8tS2efo8GXTfgJddhf5g5cQ9Q32)]]
    ]
  }
}

How can I verify the signature successfully?
